# While queueing notifications with PushSharp nothing happens at all

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I tried to send Apple push notification with PushSharp library like that:

```
public class Push
{
    private readonly PushBroker _push;

    private static Push _instance;

    public static Push Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Push()); }
    }

    public Push()
    {
        _push = new PushBroker();
        _push.OnNotificationSent += new NotificationSentDelegate(_push_OnNotificationSent);
        _push.OnNotificationFailed += new NotificationFailedDelegate(_push_OnNotificationFailed);
        _push.OnServiceException += new ServiceExceptionDelegate(_push_OnServiceException);
        _push.OnChannelCreated += new ChannelCreatedDelegate(_push_OnChannelCreated);
        _push.OnChannelDestroyed += new ChannelDestroyedDelegate(_push_OnChannelDestroyed);
        _push.OnChannelException += new ChannelExceptionDelegate(_push_OnChannelException);
        _push.OnNotificationRequeue += new NotificationRequeueDelegate(_push_OnNotificationRequeue);
        _push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\PathToCertificate\Name.p12"), "***"), "myAppId", new PushServiceSettings()
        {
            Channels = 1,
            AutoScaleChannels = false
        });
    }

    void _push_OnNotificationRequeue(object sender, NotificationRequeueEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("requeue");
    }

    void _push_OnChannelException(object sender, IPushChannel pushChannel, Exception error)
    {
        Debug.Print("channel exception");
    }

    void _push_OnChannelDestroyed(object sender)
    {
        Debug.Print("channel destroyed");
    }

    void _push_OnChannelCreated(object sender, IPushChannel pushChannel)
    {
        Debug.Print("channel created");
    }

    void _push_OnServiceException(object sender, System.Exception error)
    {
        Debug.Print("service exception");
    }

    void _push_OnNotificationFailed(object sender, INotification notification, System.Exception error)
    {
        Debug.Print("failed");
    }

    void _push_OnNotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
        Debug.Print("sent");
    }

    public void Send(Notification notification)
    {
        _push.QueueNotification(notification);
        _push.StopAllServices("biz.sintek.Rotapost", true);
    }

    public void SendAppleNotification(string deviceToken, string text)
    {
        Send(new AppleNotification()
            .ForDeviceToken(deviceToken)
            .WithAlert(text)
            .WithSound("default"));
    }
}
```

I'm calling `SendAppleNotification` method. It returns in no time but no exceptions throwed, no events called, no notifications sent and no notifications received.
I am using developer push certificate converted to .p12 format.
Double checked provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QueueNotification` method of `PushBroker` class is generic. It using generic type parameter to identify which service to use for notification send.

Solution is to pass `new AppleNotification()...` directly to the `QueueNotification`